# XMLReader return 'None' Visual Studio 2019 C#

Tags: c#

I'm using XMLReader create to read xml file.By giving xmlfilepath as input it returns 'None'

```
      public void Publish(string input, string output)
      {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new()
        {
            DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
        };            
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(input,settings)))
        {
 
        }
     }
   //For example input: C:\XML\30003.xml
```

XMLReader returns 'None' !!

Comment: Please don't tag Visual Studio for a code issue.

Comment: Not a lot to go on here. Can you show us the content of your XML file! What exactly returns "None"?

Comment: Its 64KB file having <para>,<title>,<table> contents...

Comment: Perhaps you should try to replicate your issue with a smaller file. One that you could show us the contents of.

Comment: You show us only how you create the reader but not how you read the contents of the xml. `Create` could throw an exception but return 'None'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the read function after "Create". reader.Read();

Comment: I think using this it's not completely reading the xml file getting only this on the reader  `"XmlDeclaration, Value=\"version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"UTF-8\\\"\"" `

Comment: @priyankamanogaran, Yes, you will have to implement a loop to read the file, because the "Read" will read the file line by line.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something "interesting" with the reader you created.

As seen here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.read?view=net-7.0#examples

```
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("items.xml", settings);

reader.MoveToContent();
  // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
  while (reader.Read()) {
    switch (reader.NodeType) {
      case XmlNodeType.Element:
          Console.Write("<{0}>", reader.Name);
          break;
      case XmlNodeType.Text:
          Console.Write(reader.Value);
          break;
       case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
           Console.Write("<![CDATA[{0}]]>", reader.Value);
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
           Console.Write("<?{0} {1}?>", reader.Name, reader.Value);
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.Comment:
           Console.Write("<!--{0}-->", reader.Value);
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
           Console.Write("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.Document:
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
           Console.Write("<!DOCTYPE {0} [{1}]", reader.Name, reader.Value);
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
           Console.Write(reader.Name);
           break;
       case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
           Console.Write("</{0}>", reader.Name);
           break;
   }
}
```